# Don't really know how to create time loop for this JS function

Tags: javascript, jquery

i don't really know how to create time loop for this JS function..

**Here is that function:** [enter link description here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZbyVxP)

Just what i need is a time loop every 20 seconds for a random sort..

I used - `var ... = setInterval(..., 20000);`

And - `var ... = setTimeOut(...,20000);`

But i don't know where to connect or if someone know better way how to do that everything gonna help me with that..

Thanks a lot for any help..

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Could you try to clarify your question. Are you trying to change the loading example to cycle through the dots?

Comment: OK this is not the answer to your question however you need to change `int` to `var` in your `for` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several issues with your attempt, the below will do what you want, just adjust the timer as needed

[Updated CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNZvoJ)

```
   function loop() {  // you had $(function loop(){... here, that is not right
      $container = $('#Container'); 
      if ($container.mixItUp('isLoaded')) { // check if the plugin has been initialized
        $container.mixItUp('sort', 'random', true); // if loaded, just resort
        // change true to false, to forego the animation
      } else { 

        // if not initialized, do that now
        $container.mixItUp({
          load: {
            sort: 'random'
          },
          layout: {
            containerClass: 'list',
            display: 'block'
          }
        });

      }
    }

    $(function() {  // here you had a for loop, not sure why but the int should have been var, anyway, I removed it altogether
         setInterval(loop, 2000);
    });
```

Comment: even shorter would be `setInterval(loop, 2000);` :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BoZvEx

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var mixit = $('#Container').mixItUp({
    load: {
      sort: 'random'
    },
    layout: {
      containerClass: 'list',
      display: 'block'
    }
  });

  function loop() {
    mixit.mixItUp('sort', 'random');
  };    

  var looper = setInterval(loop, 1000);
});
```

In there, the code is inside a $(document).ready, and there first we instantiate once, with the config in the parameter, and then the method loop does exactly just one call to sort.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
  for( var i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
  {
    loop();
  }
  },20000);
});
```

I think you need this